# Using Del in a script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using del in a script like this:

```
del C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\dir\*.*
```

When the script runs the command prompt has me enter y or n for yes or no if I want to run the script. I do not want it to prompt me, I just want it to do it. How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was bash, not a scripting pro by any means.

Comment: @CognitiveCarbon has an answer that will do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

```
del c:\Users\Eric\Desktop\dir\*.* /q
```

The /q switch turns off [confirmation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/del.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 1):

If this is a bash script (assuming del is aliased to rm) as the tag suggests, use
rm -rf file or directory
Be careful though, this forces a recursive delete and will not prompt you!

Comment: what If I didn't want it recursive? what would the code look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the `/q` switch as CognitiveCarbon suggested. Along with the `/f` to delete read-only files and `/s` for recursive deletion.

You could also pipe the `y` answer to the command like this:

`echo y| del c:\Users\Eric\Desktop\dir\*.*`